# Unable to get Sum as its asking to apply group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to put the case statement but getting error asking me to use group by.

```
select  (CASE 
--WHEN  sum( GREATEST ( '0', t1.LIFT_TEAM_A )+ GREATEST ( '0', t1.LIFT_TEAM_B ))<'1'  OR le.LIFT_EXCLUDE = '1' THEN 'BAU'
when  t1.LIFT_TEAM_A = '1' AND to_char( ln.min_date_of_effect, 'yyyy-mm-dd')>= '2015-01-15' THEN 'Express' 
 WHEN t1.LIFT_TEAM_B = '1' AND to_char( ln.min_date_of_effect, 'yyyy-mm-dd')>= '2015-01-15' THEN 'Standard'
 else 'other' 
 end ) LIFT_TEAM
 FROM LIFT_DEALS T1
left join 
LENDNET.OLS_VW_APP_SUBMITTED_DATE ln
  on t1.case_id=ln.application_id
  LEFT JOIN 
  lift_exclude LE
  ON LE.CASE_ID=T1.CASE_ID
```

Code works fine however if I want to un-comment the first sum statement then I am getting error which says

> not a single-group group function

Comment: Show us sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.) https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: as sum is aggregate function so you have to use group by

Comment: first of all replace `'2015-01-15'` with `date'2015-01-15'`

Answer (score 0):

Does it really have to be a `SUM` function?

This is what you have now:

```
WHEN    SUM (
                        GREATEST ('0', t1.LIFT_TEAM_A)
                      + GREATEST ('0', t1.LIFT_TEAM_B)) < '1'
                OR le.LIFT_EXCLUDE = '1'
           THEN
              'BAU'
```

Can't it be a simple

```
WHEN      GREATEST ('0', t1.LIFT_TEAM_A)
                   + GREATEST ('0', t1.LIFT_TEAM_B) < '1'
                OR le.LIFT_EXCLUDE = '1'
           THEN
              'BAU'
```

If so, then you don't need `GROUP BY` clause as well.

By the way, why is that result compared to a *string* (`< '1'`)? Shouldn't that be a number, `< 1`?